# Cleaning Wikipedia content with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wikipedia

Hi I have made use of a python library to collect the data of a topic. For example I chose the topic of New york and I have retreived the content with the following code:

```
import wikipedia
f2 = open('newyork', 'w') 
ny = wikipedia.page("New York")
f2.write(ny.content.encode('utf8')+"\n")
```

I am able to extract the information in the format below:

```
New York is a state in the Northeastern United States and is the 27th-most extensive, fourth-most populous, and seventh-most densely populated U.S. state. New York is bordered by New Jersey and Pennsylvania to the south and Connecticut, Massachusetts, and Vermont to the east. The state has a maritime border in the Atlantic Ocean with Rhode Island, east of Long Island, as well as an international border with the Canadian provinces of Quebec to the north and Ontario to the west and north. The state of New York, with an estimated 19.8 million residents in 2015, is often referred to as New York State to distinguish it from New York City, the state's most populous city and its economic hub.
With an estimated population of 8.55 million in 2015, New York City is the most populous city in the United States and the premier gateway for legal immigration to the United States. The New York City Metropolitan Area is one of the most populous urban agglomerations in the world. New York City is a global city, exerting a significant impact upon commerce, finance, media, art, fashion, research, technology, education, and entertainment, its fast pace defining the term New York minute. The home of the United Nations Headquarters, New York City is an important center for international diplomacy and has been described as the cultural and financial capital of the world, as well as the world's most economically powerful city. New York City makes up over 40% of the population of New York State. Two-thirds of the state's population lives in the New York City Metropolitan Area, and nearly 40% live on Long Island. Both the state and New York City were named for the 17th century Duke of York, future King James II of England. The next four most populous cities in the state are Buffalo, Rochester, Yonkers, and Syracuse, while the state capital is Albany.
The earliest Europeans in New York were French colonists and Jesuit missionaries who arrived southward from settlements at Montreal for trade and proselytizing. New York had been inhabited by tribes of Algonquian and Iroquoian-speaking Native Americans for several hundred years by the time Dutch settlers moved into the region in the early 17th century. In 1609, the region was first claimed by Henry Hudson for the Dutch, who built Fort Nassau in 1614 at the confluence of the Hudson and Mohawk rivers, where the present-day capital of Albany later developed. The Dutch soon also settled New Amsterdam and parts of the Hudson Valley, establishing the colony of New Netherland, a multicultural community from its earliest days and a center of trade and immigration. The British annexed the colony from the Dutch in 1664. The borders of the British colony, the Province of New York, were similar to those of the present-day state.
Many landmarks in New York are well known to both international and domestic visitors, with New York State hosting four of the world's ten most-visited tourist attractions in 2013: Times Square, Central Park, Niagara Falls (shared with Ontario), and Grand Central Terminal. New York is home to the Statue of Liberty, a symbol of the United States and its ideals of freedom, democracy, and opportunity. In the 21st century, New York has emerged as a global node of creativity and entrepreneurship, social tolerance, and environmental sustainability. New York's higher education network comprises approximately 200 colleges and universities, including Columbia University, Cornell University, New York University, and Rockefeller University, which have been ranked among the top 35 in the world.


== History ==


=== 16th century ===
In 1524, Giovanni da Verrazzano, an Italian explorer in the service of the French crown, explored the Atlantic coast of North America between the Carolinas and Newfoundland, including New York Harbor and Narragansett Bay. On April 17, 1524 Verrazanno entered New York Bay, by way of the Strait now called the Narrows into the northern bay which he named Santa Margherita, in honour of the King of France's sister. Verrazzano described it as "a vast coastline with a deep delta in which every kind of ship could pass" and he adds: "that it extends inland for a league and opens up to form a beautiful lake. This vast sheet of water swarmed with native boats". He landed on the tip of Manhattan and perhaps on the furthest point of Long Island. Verrazanno's stay in this place was interrupted by a storm which pushed him north towards Martha's Vineyard.
In 1540 French traders from New France built a chateau on Castle Island, within present-day Albany; due to flooding, it was abandoned the next year. In 1614, the Dutch under the command of Hendrick Corstiaensen, rebuilt the French chateau, which they called Fort Nassau. Fort Nassau was the first Dutch settlement in North America, and was located along the Hudson River, also within present-day Albany. The small fort served as a trading post and warehouse. Located on the Hudson River flood plain, the rudimentary "fort" was washed away by flooding in 1617, and abandoned for good after Fort Orange (New Netherland) was built nearby in 1623.


=== 17th century ===

Henry Hudson's 1609 voyage marked the beginning of European involvement with the area. Sailing for the Dutch East India Company and looking for a passage to Asia, he entered the Upper New York Bay on September 11 of that year. Word of his findings encouraged Dutch merchants to explore the coast in search for profitable fur trading with local Native American tribes.
During the 17th century, Dutch trading posts established for the trade of pelts from the Lenape, Iroquois, and other tribes were founded in the colony of New Netherland. The first of these trading posts were Fort Nassau (1614, near present-day Albany); Fort Orange (1624, on the Hudson River just south of the current city of Albany and created to replace Fort Nassau), developing into settlement Beverwijck (1647), and into what became Albany; Fort Amsterdam (1625, to develop into the town New Amsterdam which is present-day New York City); and Esopus, (1653, now Kingston). The success of the patroonship of Rensselaerswyck (1630), which surrounded Albany and lasted until the mid-19th century, was also a key factor in the early success of the colony. The English captured the colony during the Second Anglo-Dutch War and governed it as the Province of New York. The city of New York was recaptured by the Dutch in 1673 during the Third Anglo-Dutch War (1672–1674) and renamed New Orange. It was returned to the English under the terms of the Treaty of Westminster a year later.


== References ==


== Further reading ==

French, John Homer (1860). Historical and statistical gazetteer of New York State. Syracuse, New York: R. Pearsall Smith. OCLC 224691273. (Full text via Google Books.)
New York State Historical Association (1940). New York: A Guide to the Empire State. New York City: Oxford University Press. ISBN 978-1-60354-031-5. OCLC 504264143. (Full text via Google Books.)


== External links ==
New York at DMOZ
 Geographic data related to New York at OpenStreetMap
```

**The Problems:**

**Problem 1:**

I have a trouble in trying to remove all the contents from the section " Reference and Further Reading"

For example:

```
== History ==

  some text under the section History

=== 17th century ===

  some text under the section 17 century

=== 19th century ===

  some text under the section 19 century


== References ==

  some references


== Further reading ==

  some further reading sources
```

Desired Result:

```
== History ==

  some text under the section History

=== 17th century ===

  some text under the section 17 century

=== 19th century ===

  some text under the section 19 century
```

**Problem 1B:**

I will be getting the content of many topics so there will be many references to delete , how can I do it?

For example I like to delete all sections that begin with "Reference" and "Further Reading":

```
== New York ==

== References ==

== Further reading ==


== California ==


== References ==

== Further reading ==


== Floria ==


== References ==

== Further reading ==
```

Desired Result:

```
== New York ==




== California ==




== Floria ==
```

Sorry for the long post and please forgive me as I have very little knowledge of python.

All advice and help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit**

**Current Problem**

Hi osantana,

I have tried the code that you have provided as shown below:

```
import wikipedia
import re


f2 = open('osantana', 'w') 
ny = wikipedia.page("New York")



section_title_re = re.compile("^=+\s+.*\s+=+$")
raw_content = ny.content
content = []
skip = False
for l in raw_content.splitlines():
    line = l.strip()
    if "== References ==" in line.lower():
        skip = True  # replace with break if this is the last section
        continue
    if "== Further reading ==" in line.lower():
        skip = True  # replace with break if this is the last section
        continue

    if "== External links ==" in line.lower():
        skip = True  # replace with break if this is the last section
        continue
    if section_title_re.match(line):
        skip = False
        continue
    if skip:
        continue
    content.append(line)

content = '\n'.join(content) + '\n'


f2.write(content.encode('utf8')+"\n")
```

It works fine for all except this 3 part:

Original File:

```
== References ==
Index of New York-related articles
Outline of New York – organized list of topics about New York

== Further reading ==

French, John Homer (1860). Historical and statistical gazetteer of New York State. Syracuse, New York: R. Pearsall Smith. OCLC 224691273. (Full text via Google Books.)
New York State Historical Association (1940). New York: A Guide to the Empire State. New York City: Oxford University Press. ISBN 978-1-60354-031-5. OCLC 504264143. (Full text via Google Books.)
```

Result of the code:

```
Index of New York-related articles
Outline of New York – organized list of topics about New York


French, John Homer (1860). Historical and statistical gazetteer of New York State. Syracuse, New York: R. Pearsall Smith. OCLC 224691273. (Full text via Google Books.)
New York State Historical Association (1940). New York: A Guide to the Empire State. New York City: Oxford University Press. ISBN 978-1-60354-031-5. OCLC 504264143. (Full text via Google Books.)
```

The headings were removed but the content is still intact.

Comment: In your last try you need to use '= further reading =' string all in lower-case because you compare it with line.lower().

Comment: https://gist.github.com/osantana/568029e8892ce596e5e20aac593a4f36 (I tried the following code and I think it's working)

Comment: You are correct. I have changed it to lower case and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that Reference/Further Reading are not the last sections in all pages. If those topics are the last sections replace the highlighted code below with a `break` command.

```
import re

def parse(raw_content):
    section_title_re = re.compile("^=+\s+.*\s+=+$")
    content = []
    skip = False
    for l in raw_content.splitlines():
        line = l.strip()
        if "= references =" in line.lower():
            skip = True  # replace with break if this is the last section
            continue
        if "= further reading =" in line.lower():
            skip = True  # replace with break if this is the last section
            continue
        if section_title_re.match(line):
            skip = False
            continue
        if skip:
            continue
        content.append(line)

    return '\n'.join(content) + '\n'

print(parse(ny.content))
```

Comment: Hi osantana,  I have just added a Problem 1b to further explain the problem that I am facing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem... I hope that my solution works for you. Tell me here If it doesn't work well and I fix it.

Comment: Hi osatana I have a very weird result. I tried the coding, maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you missed 'line = l.strip()' that removes the '\n' at the end of line to match the regex and other if's.

Comment: sorry again , i am 1 min late again , i have just edited my post

Answer (score 2):

For **problem 2** you could do something like this

```
contents = re.sub('=+\s*.+\s*=+', '', contents)
```

Just remember to `import re`, the regular expressions module.

The method being used is `re.sub(pattern, repl, string)`. `pattern` is a regular expression pattern* (the [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) provides an overview on it).

`repl` is what you want to replace all occurrences of the pattern with. In this case you want to remove the pattern, so just use an empty string as the replacement.

`string` is of course the string you're performing the substitution on. This method *returns* the final result, so if you want to *overwrite* the original string, just assign the returned value back to the input string.

**Here's the pattern I used explained just in case**. `'=+\s*.+\s*=+'` means any part of the string where there is one or more equal sign (`=+`), followed by zero or more spaces (`\s*`), followed by one or more of *any* character (`.+`), followed again by zero or more spaces (`\s*`), finally ending with one or more equal signs (`=+`).

For **problem 1** I'd say you could probably accomplish what you want to using regular expressions as well, and the `re` module makes it pretty easy. The link I gave above should help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For problem 1 : I am stuck because if I can find the section for example : ==reference== , how do I make my program delete all the content in there before moving to the next section?

Comment: You could use regular expressions to read the header itself and all the content up until the _next_ header and delete that. I'm not that good at writing them, but it shouldn't be too hard with some trial and error!

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_data(f):
    def inner(word):
        text=f(word)
        text=text.encode("utf-8",errors='ignore').decode("utf-8")
        text=re.sub("https?:.*(?=\s)",'',text)
        text=re.sub("[’‘\"]","'",text)
        text=re.sub("[^\x00-\x7f]+",'',text)
        text=re.sub('[#&\\*+/<>@[\]^`{|}~ \t\n\r]',' ',text)
        text=re.sub('\(.*?\)','',text)
        text=re.sub('\=\=.*?\=\=','',text)
        text=re.sub(' , ',',',text)
        text=re.sub(' \.','.',text)
        text=re.sub("  +",' ',text)
        text=re.sub(";",'and',text)
        return text.strip()
        
    return inner

@clean_data
def get_data(word):
    try:
        data = wikipedia.summary("Orange",sentences=300)
    except wikipedia.DisambiguationError as e:
        print("picking the data from:",e.options[:3])
        data=''.join([wikipedia.summary(s,sentences=100) for s in e.options[:3]])
    return data

data=get_data("Orange")
```